# How to fix unwanted printing in python class

Tags: python-3.x

So, I might just be getting the basics confused here. But, it is printing even if I don't call the class.

I have tried putting it in a function, but only when I run the function there are problems.

```
class something_im_doing_wrong(): 
   print('this should not be printing unless I call the class') 

   def __init__(self): 
      self.info = 'weird'
```

Now, the output is

```
this should not be printing unless I call the class
```

Even though I haven't called the class it is printing

I expect the output to be nothing, yet is is still printing. I want it so it only prints when I call the class.

Comment: Put it inside __init__(self):
Print will be called when instantiating, not defining a class.
That's the result you are looking for, right?

Comment: Yep, thanks! I was getting confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be printed when the class instance is created, put it inside the function `__init__`.

This is the **initializer method** which is automatically called whenever a new instance of a class is created.

If you want your string to get printed when you create a class, put the print statement in this function. This function gives the programmer the opportunity to set up the attributes required within the new instance by giving them their initial state/values.